# Find missing files from sequentially numbered files in a directory

Tags: batch-file, sequential

I have about 300 000 files in a directory. They are sequentially numbered - x000001, x000002, ..., x300000. But some of these files are missing and I need to write an output text file containing the missing file numbers. The following code does it only up to 10 000 files:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "log=%cd%\logfile.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /ad /b /s') do (
 pushd "%%a"
  for /L %%b in (10000,1,19999) do (
   set a=%%b
   set a=!a:~-4!
   if not exist "*!a!.csv" >>"%log%" echo "%%a - *!a!.csv"
  )
 popd
)
```

How to extend it to 3 * 10^5 files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1 - simple but slow

If all 300000 CSV files are in current directory on executing the batch file, this batch code would do the job.

```
@echo off
set "log=%cd%\logfile.txt"
del "%log%" 2>nul
for /L %%N in (1,1,9) do if not exist *00000%%N.csv echo %%N - *00000%%N.csv>>"%log%"
for /L %%N in (10,1,99) do if not exist *0000%%N.csv echo %%N - *0000%%N.csv>>"%log%"
for /L %%N in (100,1,999) do if not exist *000%%N.csv echo %%N - *000%%N.csv>>"%log%"
for /L %%N in (1000,1,9999) do if not exist *00%%N.csv echo %%N - *00%%N.csv>>"%log%"
for /L %%N in (10000,1,99999) do if not exist *0%%N.csv echo %%N - *0%%N.csv>>"%log%"
for /L %%N in (100000,1,300000) do if not exist *%%N.csv echo %%N - *%%N.csv>>"%log%"
set "log="
```

### Solution 2 - faster but more difficult to understand

This second solution is definitely much faster than above as it processes the list of file names in current directory from first file name to last file name.

In case of last file is not `x300000.csv`, the batch code below just writes one more line into the log file with the information from which number to expected end number 300000 files are missing in current directory.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Delete log file before running file check.
set "log=%cd%\logfile.txt"
del "%log%" 2>nul

rem Define initial value for the number in the file names.
set "Number=0"

rem Define the file extension of the files.
set "Ext=.csv"

rem Define beginning of first file name with number 1.
set "Name=x00000"

rem Define position of dot separating name from extension.
set "DotPos=7"

rem Process list of files matching the pattern of fixed length in current
rem directory sorted by file name line by line. Each file name is compared
rem case-sensitive with the expected file name according to current number.
rem A subroutine is called if current file name is not equal expected one.
for /F "delims=" %%F in ('dir /B /ON x??????%Ext% 2^>nul') do (
    set /A Number+=1
    if "!Name!!Number!%Ext%" NEQ "%%F" call :CheckDiff "%%F"
)

rem Has last file not expected number 300000, log the file numbers
rem of the files missing in current directory with a single line.
if "%Number%" NEQ "300000" (
    set /A Number+=1
    echo All files from number !Number! to 300000 are also missing.>>"%log%"
)
endlocal

rem Exit this batch file to jump to predefined label EOF (End Of File).
goto :EOF

rem This is a subroutine called from main loop whenever current file name
rem does not match with expected file name. There are two reasons possible
rem with file names being in expected format:

rem 1. One leading zero must be removed from variable "Name" as number
rem    has increased to next higher power of 10, i.e. from 1-9 to 10,
rem    from 10-99 to 100, etc.

rem 2. The next file name has really a different number as expected
rem    which means there are one or even more files missing in list.

rem The first reason is checked by testing if the dot separating name
rem and extension is at correct position. One zero from end of string
rem of variable "Name" is removed if this is the case and then the
rem new expected file name is compared with the current file name.

rem Is the perhaps newly determined expected file name still not
rem equal the current file name, the expected file name is written
rem into the log file because this file is missing in list.

rem There can be even more files missing up to current file name. Therefore
rem the number is increased and entire subroutine is executed once more as
rem long as expected file name is not equal the current file name.

rem The subroutine is exited with goto :EOF if the expected file name
rem is equal the current file name resulting in continuing in main
rem loop above with checking next file name from directory listing.

:CheckDiff
set "Expected=%Name%%Number%%Ext%"
if "!Expected:~%DotPos%,1!" NEQ "." (
    set "Name=%Name:~0,-1%"
    set "Expected=!Name!%Number%%Ext%"
)
if "%Expected%" EQU %1 goto :EOF
echo %Expected%>>"%log%"
set /A Number+=1
goto CheckDiff
```

---

For understanding the used commands in both solutions and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `call /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `if /?`
- `goto /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

Comment: Yes, it does work. But its been running for about 4 hours now and less than 20% has been done. It will be nice to have a running index scroll on the prompt, otherwise there is just a cursor blinking forever without any indication of how far the run has come along.

Comment: Yes, I thought by myself already that this approach is very slow. Much faster would be processing the list of file names in current directory sorted by name line by line looking on each line if the number left to file extension matches current list line number. But this approach would work only if the file name part left to number is identical for all 300 000 files in directory as otherwise the sorting by file name done by command __dir__ would not result in getting the file names listed according to number. Is the file name part left to the number identical for all files?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /F %%a in ('copy /Z "%~F0" NUL') do set "CR=%%a"

set "num=1000000"
del logfile.txt 2> NUL
< NUL (for %%a in (*.csv) do (
   set /A num+=1
   set /P "=!num:~1!!CR!"
   if "x!num:~1!" neq "%%~Na" call :missingFile "%%~Na"
))
goto :EOF


:missingFile file
echo x%num:~1%.csv>> logfile.txt
echo x%num:~1%.csv Missing
set /A num+=1
if "x%num:~1%" neq "%~1" goto missingFile
exit /B
```